# Excel : If cell contains certain value then put certain text in new cell

Tags: excel

I have 19000 data in excel, which contain random numbers.
I want to characterized that numbers in new cell (A) like
if number between 1 to 10 then fill hello in A cell,
and if number between 11 to 20 then fill Charli in A cell and so on.
please give me some suggestion, how i make a formula for this ?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=if(AND(A1>=1,A1<=10),"hello", if(AND(A1>=11,A1<=20),"Charli", "No"))
```

Comment: Thanks for solution but this formula for only A1 cell, i want to check for complete data in a column, like A1 to A30.

Comment: Do you want it to look to see if any value in A1:A30 is between 1-10, or do you just want to check A1 and then A2, A3 etc.?

Comment: A1, A2 and A3 but i got your point thanks for the solution again :)